# HTML element test?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am writing an automated test script using ruby.

I use a require watir-webdriver statement in my ruby script.

How can I check that the following HTML tag is on the page:

```
<h3>Sale Price</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
browser.h3(:text => "Sale Price").exists?
```

It should return `true` or `false`.